# Changing the default data type in numpy.asarray

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am using `numpy.asarray` in my project to handle arrays due to its superb efficiency comparing with default Python lists. I am also supposed to take care of memory utilization when allocating the array because my program can receive big data in gigabytes. While checking [numpy.asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html), I found out that the data type is inferred from the array itself unless stated. Thus, I have the following array:

```
np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in X])
```

When I print `print X.dtype`, I got `int64`. Since the array `X` here always contains binary values, 0 or 1, I thought to use `dtype=np.int8` to reduce the memory needed when allocating space. But I am not sure if this is a good idea! Should I stick with the default `int64`? Could `int8` lose any data precisions that I cannot think of?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [NumPy Manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html):

> ### Array types and conversions between types
>
> ```
> Data type    Description
>
> ...
> int8         Byte (-128 to 127)
> ...
> ```

If you are only going to put binary values in the array than it will be just fine. You won't lose any data precision.

---

You could even think to set data type to `bool_` which is stored as a byte and will definitely be the best solution for your memory and works as an `int` too.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.asarray([1,0,1,0], dtype=np.bool_)
>>> x
array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> x + 2
array([3, 2, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain how to implement `bool_ `?